# XML3D css transformations vs custom transform property

Tags: javascript, css-transforms, xml3d

Which one: css transform property or custom [xml3D](http://xml3d.org/) `<transform>` element I'm supposed to use when using this library? 
Providing two mechanisms to do the same thing is kinda unclear to me.
I see that transformations based on transform element are flawed somehow because you need to define them with unique id in order to use, therefore 
they clutter the document namespace.

Are the css property based transform an attempt to fix it?
Which one I should use in long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed that there are two mechanisms to do the same thing. On the long run, we will support CSS transform. However, you will still be able to reference dataflow graphs, i.e. `<data>` elements that provide a transform entry in order to be able to generate dynamic transformations. The `<transform>` element will become obsolete in 5.0.